# jquery submit strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, submit

why if I put some code with "if" inside a submit function the method (apparently) always returns a true and submits the form?

example

```
    var test = "test";

    $("#contact_form").submit(function(){

            if (test == "random"){

            }



            return false;

    });
```

whenever I put an if like this with or without any code it always submits.

Comment: try event.preventDefault() instead of return false;

Comment: Returning `false` is equivalent to calling both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`. Something else is wrong.

Comment: @sje397 The form will submit if there is an error in the `if` statement that causes the code to stop running before hitting the `return false`. So stopping the submit before any other functions or code is preferred to `return false`.

Comment: @jen: That's what I meant by 'something else'. Surely fixing that is even more preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#contact_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        if (test === "random"){

        }
});
```

Stop the default action before you run any code. And, add `===`. It checks against type as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what code you write inside the if block. If you write return true by mistake or have any js error then it will submit the form. If you are trying to make any ajax call when you submit the form then prevent the default form submit in the submit handler. This is as good as returning false.

```
$("#contact_form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```